# ValueError raised unexpectedly when using UIList helper function sort_items_by_name

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I'm trying to figure out how to use filter functions in classes derived from [UIList](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UIList.html). My very simple example uses the reordering capability of `filter_items`, controlled by two flags. The flags are both `BoolProperty` annotations of my class. When `use_order_name` is `False`, no reordering is performed.  When `use_order_name` is `True` `sort_items_by_name` is used to sort the list into alphabetical order.

When the list is sorted, `use_name_reverse` is `False`, the list is presented in ascending sort order.  This works fine.  When `use_name_reverse` is `True`, the list is presented in descending order.  This fails, generating the `ValueError` exception.  I'll present the entire script below, but here's the excerpt that uses the variables.  It's lines 43 - 48 of the script:

```py
        if self.use_order_name:
            ordered = bpy.types.UI_UL_list.sort_items_by_name(items, "name")
            if self.use_name_reverse:
                flt_neworder = ordered.reverse()
            else:
                flt_neworder = ordered
```

The odd part is that the failure is not in that code, but rather when I'm drawing the panel that contains the `UIList`, at line 157 of the script:

```py
            col.template_list("TOOL_UL_List", "The_List", object,
                              "demo_list", object, "list_index")
```

Here is the error from the system console:

```
location: D:\stupi\blender\blends\python examples\annotated UIList.blend\Text:276
Python: ValueError: calling class function: sequence expected at dimension 1, not 'NoneType'
```

I assume this is because trying to reverse `ordered` is failing in some way, but I don't understand how.

Here is the entire script.

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, Operator, UIList, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import IntProperty, StringProperty, CollectionProperty

class ListItem(PropertyGroup):

    name: StringProperty(
           name="Name",
           description="A name for this item",
           default="Untitled")

    prop2: StringProperty(
           name="Any other property you want",
           description="",
           default="")


class TOOL_UL_List(UIList):
    bl_idname = "TOOL_UL_List"
    layout_type = "DEFAULT"
    
    use_name_reverse: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Reverse Name",
        default=False,
        options=set(),
        description="Reverse name filtering",
    )

    use_order_name: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Name",
        default=False,
        options=set(),
        description="Sort groups by their name (case-insensitive)",
    )

    def filter_items(self, context, data, property):
        flt_flags = []
        flt_neworder = []
        items = getattr(data, property)
        if not len(items):
            return flt_flags, flt_neworder

        if self.use_order_name:
            ordered = bpy.types.UI_UL_list.sort_items_by_name(items, "name")
            if self.use_name_reverse:
                flt_neworder = ordered.reverse()
            else:
                flt_neworder = ordered

        return flt_flags, flt_neworder        

    def draw_filter(self, context, layout):

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.label(text="Order by:")
        row.prop(self, "use_order_name", toggle=True)

        icon = 'TRIA_UP' if self.use_name_reverse else 'TRIA_DOWN'
        row.prop(self, "use_name_reverse", text="", icon=icon)

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data,
                    active_progname, index, flt_flag):

        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.label(text=item.name)

        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="")

class TOOL_OT_List_Add(Operator):
    bl_idname = "tool.list_add"
    bl_label = "Add"
    bl_description = "add a new item to the list."
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context.active_object.demo_list.add()
        return {'FINISHED'}

class TOOL_OT_List_Remove(Operator):
    bl_idname = "tool.list_remove"
    bl_label = "Add"
    bl_description = "Remove an new item from the list."
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object 
                and context.active_object.demo_list
                and len(context.active_object.demo_list))
    
    def execute(self, context):
        alist = context.active_object.demo_list
        index = context.active_object.list_index
        context.active_object.demo_list.remove(index)
        context.active_object.list_index = min(max(0, index - 1), len(alist) - 1)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class TOOL_OT_List_Reorder(Operator):
    bl_idname = "tool.list_reorder"
    bl_label = "Add"
    bl_description = "add a new item to the list."
    
    direction: bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=(('UP', 'Up', ""),
                                              ('DOWN', 'Down', ""),))
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return (context.active_object 
                and context.active_object.demo_list
                and len(context.active_object.demo_list) > 1)

    def move_index(self):
        index = bpy.context.active_object.list_index
        list_length = len(bpy.context.active_object.demo_list) - 1
        new_index = index + (-1 if self.direction == 'UP' else 1)
        bpy.context.active_object.list_index = max(0, min(new_index, list_length))

    def execute(self, context):
        alist = context.object.demo_list
        index = context.object.list_index

        neighbor = index + (-1 if self.direction == 'UP' else 1)
        alist.move(neighbor, index)
        self.move_index()
        return {'FINISHED'}

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
class TOOL_PT_Panel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_idname = "TOOL_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "Panel UIList"
    bl_description = "Demonstration of UIList Features"
    bl_options = {
        'HEADER_LAYOUT_EXPAND',
    }

    def draw(self, context):
        object = context.active_object

        row = self.layout.row()
        row.alignment = "CENTER"
        row.label(text=object.name)

        row = self.layout.row()
        row.alignment = "CENTER"

        if object:

            col = row.column(align=True)
            col.template_list("TOOL_UL_List", "The_List", object,
                              "demo_list", object, "list_index")

            col = row.column(align=True)
            col.operator("tool.list_add", text="", icon="ADD")
            col.operator("tool.list_remove", text="", icon="REMOVE")

            if len(object.demo_list) > 1:
                col.operator("tool.list_reorder", text="",
                    icon="TRIA_UP").direction = "UP"
                col.operator("tool.list_reorder", text="",
                    icon="TRIA_DOWN").direction = "DOWN"

            row = self.layout.row()
            if object.list_index >= 0 and object.demo_list:
                item = object.demo_list[object.list_index]
                row = self.layout.row()
                row.prop(item, "name")
                row.prop(item, "prop2")

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
classes = [
    ListItem,
    TOOL_UL_List,
    TOOL_OT_List_Add,
    TOOL_OT_List_Remove,
    TOOL_OT_List_Reorder,
    TOOL_PT_Panel,
]

def register():
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(c)

    bpy.types.Object.demo_list = CollectionProperty(type = ListItem)
    bpy.types.Object.list_index = IntProperty(name = "Index for demo_list",
                                             default = 0)


def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Object.demo_list
    del bpy.types.Object.list_index
    for c in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(c)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
```

Here is a 3.0 blend file that demonstrates the problem.  Open it.  Run the script.  The cube should be selected.  The panel will show up at the bottom of the tool panel in the viewport sidebar (it should already be opened.)  Click the down arrow on the right of the bottom row to reproduce the issue.

[image]

Comment: `ordered.reverse()` reverses ordered in place and returns None :)

Comment: doh.  i knew that.  write it up as answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In detail, here's the problem:

I made a Python programming mistake.  As pointed out in a comment on the question

> `ordered.reverse()` reverses the order in place and returns `None`.

The bug doesn't show up at the call site, or within the function that makes the call, because the result is immediately returned but not used in the function.

My confusion stemmed from not realizing that the call to `template_list` results in a call to the filter function and that it was `template_list` trying to use the result of the filter function that was the source of the attempt to dereference `None` because `None` had been returned instead of the desired result.

The fix is straightforward: rewrite the if statement to properly use the `reverse` function:

```py
        if self.use_order_name:
            flt_neworder = bpy.types.UI_UL_list.sort_items_by_name(items, "name")
            if self.use_name_reverse:
                flt_neworder.reverse()
```